# cakephp relational table model setup

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

i need some help, i have a 3 tables, they are: model, model_profile, profile

what i have right now is:

linked model to model_profile

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Perfil' => array(
            'className' => 'Modelo_perfile',
            'foreignKey' => 'modelo_id',
        ),
        'Fotos' => array(
            'className' => 'Modelo_foto',
            'foreignKey' => 'modelo_id',
        ),
    );
```

but i need to link model_perfile to perfile so when i call $this->Model->find('all') i get the model profile name.

the Modelo_perfile table is just ids

```
id | model_id | profile_id
```

is there a way to link this on cakephp models???

anyone can help?? Thanks.

Comment: Models should be singualize and writen from upperletter, tables lowercases and pluarize

Comment: You really should follow the documentation and the conventions. Also: Sticking to english names for coding is also a very good practice.

Comment: yeah sorry i just wrote this fast, do you have any idea how to link this 3 tables relation??

Comment: You writen about hasMany relation but Your modelo_perfile look like HABTM relation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to **kicaj** i've found my solution

i had to use a  haamanyandbelongstomany relation

here is the result:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Perfile' => array(
            'className' => 'Perfile',
            'joinTable' => 'modelo_perfiles',
            'foreignKey' => 'modelo_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'perfil_id',
            'unique' => true,
        )
    );
```

Thanks everyone :)